# using stars when declaring an array

Tags: pointers, multidimensional-array, constants

I have two questions regarding the multidimensional arrays. I declared a 3D array using two stars but when I try to access the elements I get a used-without-initializing error.

```
unsigned **(test[10]);
**(test[0]) = 5;
```

Howcome I get that error while when I use the following code, I don't get an error - What's the difference?

```
unsigned test3[10][10][10];
**(test3[0]) = 5;
```

My second question is this: I'm trying to port a piece of code that was written for Unix to Windows. One of the lines is this:

`unsigned **(precomputedHashesOfULSHs[nnStruct->nHFTuples]);`

***nHFTuples is of type int but it's not a constant**, and this the error that I'm getting;

```
error C2057: expected constant expression
```

Is it possible that I'm getting this error because I'm running it on Windows not Unix? - and how would I solve this problem? I can't make nHFTuples a constant because the user will need to provide the value for it!

Comment: Ok, your usage of test3 is an error. (Multidimensional arrays are NOT implemented as a pointer to pointer to array.)  What compiler did you use for "unix", and what did you use for windows?

Comment: This code was originally written for Unix (don't know what compiler), but I'm trying to run it on Visual Studio 2010 C++

Comment: Wait? Now you're saying that you're using C++?  Why did you say it was C?  The answer is obvious then - replace that with an std::vector.

Comment: @Arafangion looks like he's using Visual C++ to compile C code (which it has no problem doing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first one, you didn't declare a 3D array, you declared an array of 10 pointers to pointers to unsigned ints. When you dereference it, you're dereferencing a garbage pointer.

In the second one, you declared the array correctly but you're using it wrong. Arrays are not pointers and you don't dereference them.

Do this:

```
unsigned test3[10][10][10];
test3[0][0][0] = 5;
```

To answer your second question, you have to use a number that can be known at compile time as the size of an array. GCC has a nonstandard extension that allows you to do that, but it's not portable and not part of the standard (though C99 introduced them). To fix it, you'll have to use `malloc` and `free`:

```
int i, j, k;

unsigned*** precomputedHashOfULSHs = malloc(nnStruct->nHFTuples * sizeof(unsigned));

for (i = 0; i < firstDimensionLength; ++i) {
    precomputedHashOfULSHs[i] = malloc(sizeOfFirstDimension * sizeof(unsigned));

    for (j = 0; j < secondDimensionLength; ++j) {
        precomputedHashOfULSHs[i][j] = malloc(sizeOfSecondDimension * sizeof(unsigned));

        for (k = 0; k < sizeOfSecondDimension; ++k)
            precomputedHashOfULSHs[i][j][k] = malloc(sizeof(unsigned));
    }
}

// then when you're done...

for (i = 0; i < firstDimensionLength; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < secondDimensionLength; ++j) {
        for (k = 0; k < sizeOfSecondDimension; ++k)
            free(precomputedHashOfULSHs[i][j][k]);

        free(precomputedHashOfULSHs[i][j]);
    }

    free(precomputedHashOfULSHs[i]);
}

free(precomputedHashOfULSHs);
```

(Pardon me if that allocation/deallocation code is wrong, it's late :))

Comment: Which means that they are part of the C99 standard. Alas, Visual Studio does not support C99.

Comment: So what does 'unsigned **(precomputedHashesOfULSHs[nnStruct->nHFTuples]);' exactly do then?

Comment: @RoronoaZoro it doesn't do anything because it's illegal; the value of `nnStruct->nHFTuples` can only be known at _runtime_ but you need a number that's known at _compile time_ to be used as the size of an array

Comment: @Arafangion no it doesn't in this case (evidenced by his compiler error); the version of C that Visual Studio supports doesn't have VLAs which were introduced in C99

Comment: @Arafangion ...... he's using Visual Studio doesn't support C99, that's the point

Comment: So if I was using C99, it would only be a variable length 1D array? I still can't fully picture pointer to pointer to unsigned!!

Comment: @RoronoaZoro yes that's correct. And try drawing it on a piece of paper: `a ---> b ----> unsigned`

Comment: @Arafangion there's no point in discussing what is valid in C99 (unless the OP explicitly asks, which he did after you talked about it) because we might as well be talking about what's legal in Java or C#

Comment: @SethCarnegie I can picture it now. But why would anyone do such a thing? Isn't a ----> unsigned just much easier?

Comment: @RoronoaZoro yes but multiple levels of pointers simulate runtime-sized 3d, 4d, 5d, etc. arrays which you can't do with one pointer. A `unsigned*` is like a 1d array, an `unsigned**` is like a 2d array, an `unsigned***` is like a 3d array, etc.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: The original code is, as best as we can tell, C99. We assume that because it's using features that are either compiler extensions, or exist in C99.  His new compiler doesn't support that.  If his original code was in Java 1.6, but he was attempting to compile it with say... Java 1.2, we would be having the same discussion, but with reference to Java 1.6 instead.

Comment: @Arafangion that's true, I just felt like too much was being said about what was legal and what wasn't in C99 or whatever which confuses the matter to the questioner

Comment: @SethCarnegie: just to make sure I got it 'unsigned **(precomputedHashesOfULSHs[nnStruct->nHFTuples]);' simulate a runtime-sized 3d array right?

Comment: @Arafangion: sorry about that - I'll mention it explicitly next time.

Comment: `unsigned **(precomputedHashesOfULSHs[nnStruct->nHFTuples]);` this simulates a 2d of an array so it should be simulating 3d right?

Comment: @RoronoaZoro if it were C99, then it would be simulating a 3d array, yes

Comment: Please use one of the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead of comments for extended discussions.

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't specify it, I think you're using a compiler on unix that supports C99 (SUch as GCC), whereas the compiler you use on windows does not support it. (Visual Studio uses only C89 here).

You have three options:

1. You can hard-code a suitable maximum array size.
2. You could allocate the array yourself using malloc or calloc. Don't forget to free it when you're done.
3. Port the program to C++, and use std::vector.

If you choose option 3, then you'll want something like:

```
std::vector<unsigned int> precomputedHashOfULSHs;
```

For a single-dimension vector, or for a two-dimensional vector, use:

```
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > precomputedHashOfULSHs;
```

Do note that vectors default to being empty, of zero length, so you will need to add each element from the original set.

In the case of test3 as an example, you'll want:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int> > > precomputedHashOfULSHs;
precomputedHashOfULSHs.resize(10);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    precomputedHashOfULSHs[i].resize(10);
    for(int ii=0; ii<10; ii++) {
        precomputedHashOfULSHs[i][ii].resize(10);
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should be right.  C++ will manage the memory of that vector for you automatically.

Comment: I want to replace 'unsigned **(precomputedHashesOfULSHs[nnStruct->nHFTuples]);' with something that won't through an error. Can you explain to me a little more?

Comment: @RoronoaZoro: I have the impression that your indeed compiling the project as C, not C++. This means you're essentially using C89, so this answer here is irrelevant.  I suggest you accept Seth's answer, because it's the best that can be done here.

Comment: @RoronoaZoro: I suggest you check and find out.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio and the files' extension is .cpp - Can I still be using C?

Comment: You are most likely using C++, then.  #include <vector> to get the vectors.  Do note that your team might have chosen to use the common subset of C and C++.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure about what `unsigned **(precomputedHashesOfULSHs[nnStruct->nHFTuples]);` mean exactly. Is it simulating a 3d array? I need to know so I can decide on how to implement vectors to replace it?

Comment: @RoronoaZoro: I don't know your code base, it most likely is.

Comment: @RoronoaZoro: If you don't know C++, I recommend sticking with Seth's answer - his answer will work in the common subset of C and C++. (Although you may have warnings because of the lack of casts, which is correct C but not quite correct C++).